# Build a balanced binary tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree

```js
const Tree = function(value){
  this.value = value
  this.right = null
  this.left = null
}


Tree.prototype.insert = function(number){
  if(this.left === null){
    this.left = new Tree(number)
  } else if(this.right === null){
    this.right = new Tree(number)
  } else {
    this.left.insert(number)
  }
}

const arbre = new Tree(10)

arbre.insert(5)
arbre.insert(2)
arbre.insert(1)
arbre.insert(20)
arbre.insert(6)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arbre,null,4))
```

I'm trying to build a balanced binary tree. It means that each time I'm inserting a value it will fill the left node first and then the right node, and so on. Something like that:

```js
 0
/ \
1  2
/\ /
34 5
```

My code keep building in the left side but doesn't go back in the right side to maintain the balance of the tree.
It does something like:

```js
      0
     / \
     1   2
     /\ 
     34
    /
    5
```

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: It does something like:

Comment: @Geeky please check my snippet again

Comment: This seems like an assignment. In your example: usually the left child is smaller than its parent, and the right side is greater than its parent. Example: root: 3, level 1: 1, 5, level 2: 0, 2, 4.

Comment: I don't want to order it by value. I just want to keep it balanced while I insert nodes

Comment: I see. Well, it looks like your code only calls `this.left.insert`. You're going to need to tell it to call `this.right.insert` if you want it to start inserting on the right side of the tree.